# Find the constituents of a specific number

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how I can find constituents of a specific number. Numbers can only be:
array (700, 800, 900, 950, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300).

For example, the given number is 3500. So, components could be 1200, 1200, 1100. If the number is not evenly divisible, then need find the nearest values with the minimum remainder.

Here's what I got:

```
<?php
$amount = 3000;

$sizes = array(1300, 1200, 1100, 1000, 950, 900, 800, 700);

$result = array();

foreach ($sizes as $size) {
    $result[$size] = floor($amount / $size);
    $amount -= $result[$size] * $size;
}

echo '<pre style="direction: ltr;">'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';

Output:

Array
(
    [1300] => 2
    [1200] => 0
    [1100] => 0
    [1000] => 0
    [950] => 0
    [900] => 0
    [800] => 0
    [700] => 0
)
```

But 1300 * 2 = 2600, when it would be nice to use 1000 * 3.

Please help me optimize it for finding the closest values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$amount = 3000;
$sizes = [ 1300, 1200, 1100, 1000, 950, 900, 800, 700 ];
$maxDepth = (int)( $amount / min($sizes) );

$result = [];
for ($depth = 1; $depth <= $maxDepth; $depth++) {
  foreach (combinations($sizes, $depth) as $combination) {
    rsort($combination);
    $remainder = $amount - array_sum($combination);
    if ($remainder >= 0) {
      $result[] = [
          'remainder' => $remainder,
          'combination' => $combination
      ];
    }
  }
}

usort($result, static function ($item1, $item2): int {
  $comparison = $item1['remainder'] <=> $item2['remainder'];
  return $comparison === 0 ? count($item1['combination']) <=> count($item2['combination']) : $comparison;
});

print_r($result);

// The following code is from: 
// https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations_with_repetitions#PHP

function combinations(array $arr, int $k): array {
  if ($k === 0) {
    return [ [] ];
  }
  if (count($arr) === 0) {
    return [];
  }
  $head = $arr[0];
  $combos = [];
  foreach (combinations($arr, $k - 1) as $subCombination) {
    array_unshift($subCombination, $head);
    $combos[] = $subCombination;
  }
  array_shift($arr);
  return array_merge($combos, combinations($arr, $k));
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 0
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1300
                    [1] => 1000
                    [2] => 700
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 0
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1300
                    [1] => 900
                    [2] => 800
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 0
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1200
                    [1] => 1100
                    [2] => 700
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 0
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1200
                    [1] => 1000
                    [2] => 800
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 0
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1200
                    [1] => 900
                    [2] => 900
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 0
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1100
                    [1] => 1100
                    [2] => 800
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 0
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1100
                    [1] => 1000
                    [2] => 900
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 0
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1100
                    [1] => 950
                    [2] => 950
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 0
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1000
                    [1] => 1000
                    [2] => 1000
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 0
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 900
                    [1] => 700
                    [2] => 700
                    [3] => 700
                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 0
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 800
                    [1] => 800
                    [2] => 700
                    [3] => 700
                )

        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 50
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1300
                    [1] => 950
                    [2] => 700
                )

        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 50
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1200
                    [1] => 950
                    [2] => 800
                )

        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 50
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1100
                    [1] => 950
                    [2] => 900
                )

        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 50
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1000
                    [1] => 1000
                    [2] => 950
                )

        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 100
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1300
                    [1] => 900
                    [2] => 700
                )

        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 100
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1300
                    [1] => 800
                    [2] => 800
                )

        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [remainder] => 100
            [combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1200
                    [1] => 1000
                    [2] => 700
                )

        )

     ... elements omitted ...

)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works absolutely correctly :)

Comment: You can quickly run out of memory with this – be aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Build a result array which contains the amount ('size') multiplied by 'times', and the 'remainder'. Then sort the result array by 'remainder', and if remainders are the same additionally by 'times':

```
$amount = 3000;
$sizes = [ 1300, 1200, 1100, 1000, 950, 900, 800, 700 ];

$result = [];

foreach ($sizes as $size) {
  $temp = (int)floor($amount / $size);
  $result[] = [
      'size' => $size,
      'times' => $temp,
      'remainder' => $amount - $temp * $size
  ];
}

usort($result, static function ($item1, $item2): int {
  $comparison = $item1['remainder'] <=> $item2['remainder'];
  return $comparison === 0 ? $item1['times'] <=> $item2['times'] : $comparison;
});

print_r($result);
```

This will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [size] => 1000
            [times] => 3
            [remainder] => 0   // best result
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [size] => 950
            [times] => 3
            [remainder] => 150   // second best result
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [size] => 700
            [times] => 4
            [remainder] => 200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [size] => 900
            [times] => 3
            [remainder] => 300
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [size] => 1300
            [times] => 2
            [remainder] => 400
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [size] => 1200
            [times] => 2         // better than next
            [remainder] => 600   // same as next
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [size] => 800
            [times] => 3         // worse than previous
            [remainder] => 600   // same as previous
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [size] => 1100
            [times] => 2
            [remainder] => 800
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks :) But I found issue, if using number 3050, it will calculate 3*1000 and reminder 50, but 3050 could be = 950 + 1000 + 1100 . Is it possible to solve it?

Comment: You only mentioned multiplication in your original post. Adding addition makes it much more complicated and is kind of a different question.

Comment: You could try out a library like https://github.com/pear/Math_Combinatorics.

Comment: Seems so, I don't ask ready code, you already help me with this part, thanks again. But maybe you could point me a right direction which should I use?

Comment: Thanks for library, I'll check it

Comment: I think that library only gives combinations (and permutations) without repetitions. But you want repetitions.

Comment: I can't say for sure about permutations, seems this library works correctly at my end. I ran it and I got at least three combinations for 3050. So I guess I can use it for my project. Thanks a lot, I trying to solve this problem for several days

Comment: I posted a second solution, you might check it out.